# 2D Interpolation of a Resampled DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, interpolation

I'd like to do a 2D interpolation of a dataframe after resampling it. The resampling part can be by day, month, or minutes. The example below is just to illustrate the process. Instead of removing the data from a dataframe column-by-column, I'd like to perform the resampling and interpolation in the dataframe itself.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.interpolate

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'time': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:30:00'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:30:00'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:30:00'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:30:00'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:30:00'),
  5: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:30:00'),
  6: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:30:00'),
  7: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:30:00')},
 'x': {0: 25.0,
  1: 25.0,
  2: 25.5,
  3: 25.5,
  4: 25.0,
  5: 25.0,
  6: 25.5,
  7: 25.5},
 'y': {0: 51.25,
  1: 51.875,
  2: 51.25,
  3: 51.875,
  4: 51.25,
  5: 51.875,
  6: 51.25,
  7: 51.875},
 'z': {0: 1.9466316037407283e-13,
  1: 1.4071156620529962e-13,
  2: 2.1328328914192035e-13,
  3: 1.5983803094022503e-13,
  4: 1.8673746631035076e-13,
  5: 1.1844342238769012e-13,
  6: 2.0592551372867335e-13,
  7: 1.341905238186683e-13}})
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
```

Then the interpolation piece:

```
interp_x = df["x"].values
interp_y = df["y"].values
interp_z = df["z"].values
interp_f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x=interp_x, y=interp_y, z=interp_z)
```

And finally, the following

```
df.resample("1M").apply(lambda r: interp_f(r["x"], r["y"]))
```

doesn't work as intended, because I get:

```
time
2015-01-31    [[1.9070031334221175e-13, 1.9070031334221175e-...
2015-02-28    [[1.9070031334221175e-13, 1.9070031334221175e-...
Freq: M, dtype: object
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I actually don't understand the output from the last command. In this example, I'd like to "group" rows by month and apply a 2D interpolation using x and y as independent variables and z as dependent variable. So I think the output of this example would be a dataframe with two rows, one for each moth, and one column containing the interpolated z values (using corresponding x and y for the month).